# How to connect an iPad Air to a Panasonic TV?

Tags: ipad

Is there a way to stream TV from my iPad to my Panasonic TV?

I am a relatively new iPad user with little expertise.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Have you tried anything yet?  Do you have an Apple TV?  Do you have a home wireless network?  Is your Panasonic TV model equipped with WiFi or an HDMI input?  Please provide as much information as you can about what you wish to accomplish with what you have.  To answer your question is difficult without more information about your TV.  Cheers.

Comment: Thanks bjbk. No I don't have an Apple TV and my Panasonic  Viera has got HDMI input as we used to run programme content theough a Windows laptop to the TV using chrome cast.

Comment: The Panasonic Viera TV supports screen mirroring from Android devices, but I can't find a way to get iOS devices to stream to it without using an Apple TV.

Answer (score 1):

Although the OP's question is a bit light on detail, (what model of Panasonic TV?) this is general information on how to stream video from an iOS device, including the iPad Air, to a television equipped with an HDMI input.

Required is a **Wireless Network** that one has access to.  Also, the TV must have an Airplay capable device attached via HDMI that is capable of receiving streaming video from the iOS device.  For example a second generation Apple TV or newer.

Connect to the Apple TV using [AirPlay](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204289).

According to Apple:

> AirPlay is compatible with the second-generation Apple TV or later. AirPlay Mirroring is available with iPhone 4s or later, iPad Pro, iPad Air or later, iPad 2 or later, iPad mini or later, and iPod touch (5th generation or later).

---

### Use AirPlay to wirelessly stream content from your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch

With AirPlay, you can stream music, photos, and videos to your Apple TV, or stream music to your AirPort Express or AirPlay-enabled speakers. And with AirPlay Mirroring, you can display your iOS screen on your Apple TV.

#### Get started

To use AirPlay, you need one of these devices:

- iPhone 4 or later. iPhone 4s or later for AirPlay Mirroring.
- iPad, iPad mini. iPad 2 or later for AirPlay Mirroring.
- iPod touch (4th generation or later). iPod touch (5th generation or later) for AirPlay Mirroring.

You can stream content to these devices:

- For photos and videos: Apple TV (2nd generation or later).
- For music: Apple TV, AirPort Express, or AirPlay-enabled speakers.

If you want to stream iTunes Store content, you also need an Internet connection.

#### Use AirPlay

1. Connect your iOS device and your AirPlay device to the same Wi-Fi network.
2. On your iOS device, swipe up from the bottom of your screen to open [Control Center.](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5858)
3. Tap AirPlay.
4. Tap the name of the device you want to stream content to. You'll see a picture of a TV screen or speaker next to each device, so you know what type of content you can stream. On iPad, you might need to scroll to see all of the available devices.

When you choose an AirPlay device, audio or video from your iOS device will play on your AirPlay-enabled speakers or on the TV that's connected to your Apple TV.

If you turn on Mirroring, you'll see your entire iOS screen on the TV that's connected to your Apple TV. Your TV will use the orientation and aspect ratio of your device. If you want the image from your device to fill your TV screen, you might need to to adjust your TV's aspect ratio or zoom settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apple's Airplay technology to stream from your iPad (or iPhone) to your tv, but you need to use an AppleTV connected to your Panasonic through an HDMI port to do so. The AppleTV device takes care of connecting the TV to the Wifi and also your device. On top of that the AppleTV has its own media viewing apps so you may not need the iPad.

Answer (score -1):

There is a way to display your videos and images on your Panasonic TV without Apple TV or HDMI cable. Download Sunshine app in your ipad and if both devices are connected with the same WIFI network it will work. It's very straightforward to use... you play the video from the app and in the top right corner there is a bottom and there you can select your TV
[Link to apple store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sunshine-transfer-backup-share/id922432715?mt=8)